# Lyx generated PDF with JavaScript encounters NotAllowedError

Tags: pdftex, lyx, javascript, adobe

I am trying to generate a pdf file that opens another pdf file with this code

```
\usepackage[pdftex]{insdljs}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Main Script
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{insDLJS}{dljs}{Document Javascript}

doesitopen = app.trustedFunction (function() {
    var reffile1,openf;
    try {
        app.alert("trying c:/temp/existing.pdf",3);
        console.println('here');
        app.beginPriv();
            app.openDoc("/c/temp/existing.pdf");
        app.endPriv();
        openf = 1;
    }
    finally {
        e = null;
    }
    app.alert("diditopen",3);

});

doesitopen();
\end{insDLJS}
```

Here is my Lyx file - it's pretty vanilla --

```
#LyX 2.0 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 413
\begin_document
\begin_header
\textclass scrartcl
\begin_preamble
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Document product, type, number and title
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Conditional text
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% DO NOT ALTER AFTER THIS POINT
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage[pdftex]{eforms}
\input{jsfunctions_bare.tex}
\end_preamble
\use_default_options false
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman times
\font_sans helvet
\font_typewriter courier
\font_default_family sfdefault
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 83
\font_tt_scale 100

\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry true
\use_amsmath 1
\use_esint 1
\use_mhchem 1
\use_mathdots 1
\cite_engine basic
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\use_refstyle 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\leftmargin 1in
\topmargin 0.75in
\rightmargin 1in
\bottommargin 1.25in
\headheight 0in
\headsep 0.5in
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation skip
\defskip medskip
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle fancy
\bullet 0 2 14 -1
\bullet 1 2 5 -1
\bullet 2 2 9 -1
\bullet 3 2 21 -1
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
\noindent
\align block

\series bold
Click below to test app.openDoc
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\noindent
\align block
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
raisebox{-1.3pt}{
\backslash
pushButton[
\backslash
CA{Export}
\backslash
A{
\backslash
JS{doesitopen();}}]{export14}{12mm}{11pt}}
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

My problem is that Adobe Refuses to execute my code despite having used `app.trustedFunction` and marked my code with `app.beginPriv()` and `app.endPriv()`

When I run Adobe Reader XI, I get this error in the JavaScript console :

> Acrobat EScript Built-in Functions Version 11.0 Acrobat SOAP 11.0
>
> NotAllowedError: Security settings prevent access to this property or
>   method. App.trustedFunction:3:Document-Level:01 Document Javascript
>
> NotAllowedError: Security settings prevent access to this property or
>   method. App.trustedFunction:1:Document-Level:01 Document Javascript
>
> NotAllowedError: Security settings prevent access to this property or
>   method. App.trustedFunction:1:Document-Level:01 Document Javascript

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll work on that -- total noob and all I have are the lyx and tex files...

Comment: I am no JavaScript expert at all, but if is just opening another `.pdf` file in Acrobat, you could use a `\href` command from `hyperref` package.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [JavaScript for Acrobat API Reference](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/acrobat_sdk/10/Acrobat10_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm?href=JS_API_AcroJSPreface.87.1.html#1515776&accessible=true), the method `app.trustedFunction` is security restricted and only allowed in batch, console and application initialization events, that is, not in document level JavaScript.

On the other hand, `app.openDoc()` doesn't need to be called in a trusted environment.

Therefore,

```
\begin{insDLJS}{dljs}{Document Javascript}
  app.openDoc('c:/temp/existing.pdf');
\end{insDLJS}
```

should already work.